# Storing 30+ flags in a single integer

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I have to store more than 30 flags(0/1) into a single integer. I can able to create 30 flag masks in Javascript using Bitwise operator like below

```
var FLAG_1 = 1 << 0; // 1
var FLAG_2 = 1 << 1; // 2
...
...
var FLAG_30 = 1 << 30;

var user1 = FLAG_1 | FLAG_16;

console.log(FLAG_1 & user1); // true
```

This works fine. But I can't create more than 30 flags because `1 << 31` goes in reverse(compliment or negative number).

Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: What's the problem? The bits are still stored properly.

Comment: What is the definition of `FLAG_16`? should we assume it as: `var FLAG_16 = 1 << 16;`

Comment: javasacript has no concept of integer - having said that, using the bitwise operators, you can get 31 bits without going into negative numbers (1<<0 to 1<<30 - that's 31 values) and you can still use 1<<31 carefully ... so you have 32 ... any more than that and you'll need to get creative

Comment: Did you try using `2 ** 31`? It seems to work fine compared to bit shifting (though is slower, it would be better if you define `FLAG_X` as constant number without calculating it each time)

Comment: FLAG_1 = 1 << 0 ... but FLAG_30 = 1 << 30 ... somewhere in there you skipped a value after <<

Comment: Since JavaScript stores *all* numbers as *64 bit floating point*, I'm not sure these bit masks save you much time.  In a language like C or Java they would, but JS? Any JavaScript experts care to comment?

Comment: using javascripts very own `Number` you can - with some skill - deal with 52 "bits" - 53 if you want to be creative

Comment: Actually you can put 32 flags there, that `1 << 31` is negative doesn't matter.

Comment: `I have to store more than 30 flags` - I guess the real question is, do you need to store more than 32, because that's more than 30, and perfectly attainable using javascript bitwise arithmetic

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Using more than one 32 bit number concatenated together.  If you know you need less than 64 say, use two 32 bit numbers.  Take the first 32 bits and handle those flags, then separately take the second 32 and handle those.

```
var test = '0421';

for( var i=0; i < test.length; i += 2 ) {
   flags = parseInt( test.substr(i,2), 10 );
   console.log(flags);
   // do comparisons here
   // call function doStuff(i, flags)
}
```

I'm not sure what your initial input value is.  I start off with a string, which can be any quantity of sets of 00 - 31.  Each can can be processed by calling a function to do the work, passing the iterator and the flags.

Comment: This is what I got in my mind also. I will just wait for few other resonses. :-)